# LocomotiveCMS - Wagon can't find content_type_template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locomotivecms

Can't use events content_type_template. Repeat official tutorial (http://doc.locomotivecms.com/guides/content-types/create), and have error: **Page not found.** Please help, i'm try resolve this problem 3 hours yet!

> **/app/content_types/events.yml**

```
name: Events

slug: events

description: List of all events

label_field_name: title

order_by: manually # default: manually, also available: created_at or any field slug

# order_direction: asc # default: asc, also available: desc

# group_by: <your field>

# public_submission_enabled: false

# public_submission_accounts: ['john@acme.net']


fields: 
- title: # Name of the field
    label: Title
    type: string
    required: true

- description: # Name of the field
    label: Description
    type: text
    required: false
    # Enable or not the RTE [html|text]
    # text_formatting: html

- event_date: # Name of the field
    label: Event date
    type: date
    required: false
```

> **/app/views/pages/events/content_type_template.liquid** **was created manually!**

```
--
title: Event template page

content_type: events

published: true
---
{% extends parent %}

{% block main %}
    <h1>{{ event.title }} on {{ event.event\_date || localized_date: '%m/%d/%Y' }}</h1>
    <p>{{ event.description }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

> **/app/views/pages/index.liquid**

```
{% extends parent %}

{% block main %}

  <ul>
    {% for event in contents.events %}
      <li><a href="/events/{{ event._slug }}">{{ event.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you still have this issue. I was running into the same problem and figured out what the problem was:

There is typo in the content_type_template.

`<h1>{{ event.title }} on {{ event.event\_date || localized_date: '%m/%d/%Y' }}</h1>`

Should be

`<h1>{{ event.title }} on {{ event.event_date || localized_date: '%m/%d/%Y' }}</h1>`

The file events.yml in the data folder contains sample data with an impossible date. in my case 2013/39/02(format y/m/d)

After this two corrections, the example worked here.